# How to plot the result of mixed effect model in R?

Tags: r, mixed-models

I wanted to fit a mixed effect model using following data with R. And I wanted to plot the modeled data to show the mean 95% CIs for the predicted values using the model.

```
tempEf <- data.frame(
  N = rep(c("Nlow", "Nhigh"), each=300),
  Myc = rep(c("AM", "ECM"), each=150, times=2),
  TRTYEAR = runif(600, 1, 15),
  ID = rep(c("1","2","3","4","5"), each=10, times=12)   #5 sites
)

# Make up some response data
tempEf$r <- 2*tempEf$TRTYEAR +                   
  -8*as.numeric(tempEf$Myc=="ECM") +
  4*as.numeric(tempEf$N=="Nlow") +
  0.1*tempEf$TRTYEAR * as.numeric(tempEf$N=="Nlow") +
  0.2*tempEf$TRTYEAR*as.numeric(tempEf$Myc=="ECM") +
  -11*as.numeric(tempEf$Myc=="ECM")*as.numeric(tempEf$N=="Nlow")+ 
  0.5*tempEf$TRTYEAR*as.numeric(tempEf$Myc=="ECM")*as.numeric(tempEf$N=="Nlow")+ 
  as.numeric(tempEf$ID) +  #Random intercepts; intercepts will increase by 1
  tempEf$TRTYEAR/10*rnorm(600, mean=0, sd=2)    #Add some noise
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP5Nt.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your current question does not have sufficient information for an answer. You have provided some sample data, but without any explanation it is impossible to infer anything from it. Also review how to create a minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided information, it is only possible to guess what you want, since you did not include any code that fits the model. Here's a suggestion how you can print/plot adjusted predictions for your mixed model, hope that helps.

There are several R packages that help you computing predictions/estimated marginal means/marginal effects. In this particular example, I'm using the [`ggeffects`-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects). You find a lot of examples and documentation on the linked website.

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(ggeffects)

tempEf <- data.frame(
  N = rep(c("Nlow", "Nhigh"), each = 300),
  Myc = rep(c("AM", "ECM"), each = 150, times = 2),
  TRTYEAR = runif(600, 1, 15),
  ID = rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), each = 10, times = 12) # 5 sites
)

# Make up some response data
tempEf$r <- 2 * tempEf$TRTYEAR +
  -8 * as.numeric(tempEf$Myc == "ECM") +
  4 * as.numeric(tempEf$N == "Nlow") +
  0.1 * tempEf$TRTYEAR * as.numeric(tempEf$N == "Nlow") +
  0.2 * tempEf$TRTYEAR * as.numeric(tempEf$Myc == "ECM") +
  -11 * as.numeric(tempEf$Myc == "ECM") * as.numeric(tempEf$N == "Nlow") +
  0.5 * tempEf$TRTYEAR * as.numeric(tempEf$Myc == "ECM") * as.numeric(tempEf$N == "Nlow") +
  as.numeric(tempEf$ID) + # Random intercepts; intercepts will increase by 1
  tempEf$TRTYEAR / 10 * rnorm(600, mean = 0, sd = 2) # Add some noise

m <- lmer(r ~ TRTYEAR * Myc + N + (1 | ID), data = tempEf)

ggpredict(m, c("TRTYEAR", "Myc"))
#> # Predicted values of r
#> 
#> # Myc = AM
#> 
#> TRTYEAR | Predicted |         95% CI
#> ------------------------------------
#>       0 |      4.11 | [ 2.59,  5.63]
#>       2 |      8.29 | [ 6.82,  9.76]
#>       6 |     16.64 | [15.24, 18.05]
#>       8 |     20.82 | [19.42, 22.22]
#>      10 |     25.00 | [23.59, 26.41]
#>      16 |     37.53 | [36.01, 39.06]
#> 
#> # Myc = ECM
#> 
#> TRTYEAR | Predicted |          95% CI
#> -------------------------------------
#>       0 |     -9.24 | [-10.77, -7.71]
#>       2 |     -4.20 | [ -5.67, -2.72]
#>       6 |      5.89 | [  4.48,  7.30]
#>       8 |     10.93 | [  9.53, 12.33]
#>      10 |     15.97 | [ 14.56, 17.38]
#>      16 |     31.10 | [ 29.58, 32.63]
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> *  N = Nhigh
#> * ID = 0 (population-level)
#> 
#> Not all rows are shown in the output. Use `print(..., n = Inf)` to show
#>   all rows.

ggpredict(m, c("TRTYEAR", "Myc")) |> plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks to answer my question! But the result of plot which I required was a broken line graph. I'm looking forward to your reply!

Comment: I'm not sure what a "broken" line graph is.